# Would this Dragons question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I was going to post the following question about Dragons in Temeraire, but looking for appropriate tags started to think it might be off topic as science based. Could I get a feeling in the room?

---

In Naomi Novik's Temeraire series Dragons are seen to mature very quickly and then live a very long time. From the information in the books Dragons seem to reach adult size in around a year, sexual maturity in at most 2 years, but can then live for up to two centuries.

Is there a real animal that this sort of growth cycle is based on?

Comment: Asking if it *resembles* a real animal, is asking mainly about animals and is off-topic. Asking if an animal *inspired* this lifespan might be on topic if we can find a quite from the author perhaps, otherwise it seems likely to attract Primarily Opinion Based answers. It's a fine line to tread for sure!

Comment: [This list of long-lived animals might be of interest](https://www.livescience.com/longest-living-animals.html); as a rule, however, at least in vertebrates, lifespan is correlated with the time to reach maturity.  So the sharks that can live up to 500 years take over a hundred to reach maturity.  Sea turtles that can live over a century take 20-30 years to reach maturity (similar to the great whales), etc.

Comment: @DavidW thanks for the page, I've snagged some of your comment to add to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### It depends.

As written, it's not entirely clear what your specific question is.

If you're wanting to know whether the growth cycles of this author's fictional dragons were based directly on a real world animal, then that would be very firmly on topic e.g. *what inspired her to make her dragons like this?*

If you're simply wanting to know whether there are any real world animals that share a similar growth pattern to those seen in the book, then that would be firmly off-topic. Stripped of the fantasy content, it's just a question about the growth patterns of mundane animals and that would be better asked elsewhere.

Comment: I shall steal your wording and go ahead and post.